# Cannot find class com.tridion.util.FileUtils in SDL Web 8

Tags: content-delivery, web8, deployer-extension

Where is the class `com.tridion.util.FileUtils` located in SDL Web 8?  When migrating a Custom Deployer from Tridion 2011 to Web 8, I have a lot of code like below:

```
import com.tridion.util.FileUtils;
import com.tridion.util.StringUtils;
com.tridion.util.FileUtils.writeFile(new File(path, file.getName() + ".xml").getAbsolutePath(), prepareMarkLogicContent(pageMeta, action));
```

I'm referencing the jar files in but cannot find the `writeFile` method on `FileUtils`.

> C:\SDL\Web\deployer\services\deployer-service

I saw a similar method in the Apache commons-io library, but I'm hoping I don't need to use that one since it also requires a 2nd encoding parameter, and I'd need to update every reference to the Tridion util library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.tridion.util.FileUtils` which was in `cd_core` pre Web8 is now moved to `cd_common_util-XXX.jar` as part of refactoring done for Web8. You can find this in `deployer\standalone\lib` folder.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the Web 8 deployer is simply backwards compatible with 2013, so for DXA we simply reuse the 2013 SI4T storage extension for example.

See http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v4/GUID-814D5C17-9320-4BC4-B50B-6CC007D79C32 for the installation documentation of it and note there is no separate topic for Web 8. Like in the download (https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/tridion-developer/m/mediagallery/1180) you also can't find a version specific part in the deployer folder.

Now I have no clue about the class `com.tridion.util.FileUtils`, maybe it was marked as internal API so you shouldn't have actually used it (which was done by marking it as deprecated if I remember correctly, since there is no other way of marking something as internal when it actually needs to be public for the class)?